# Java Derby tables are not persistent

Tags: java, sql, persistence, derby

I am using Derby embedded driver and have added derby.jar to dependencies (I'm using Eclipse).
This is how I create tables:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true;");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

Statement s=conn.createStatement();
s.execute("create table Vodici(ID int NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, ime varchar(20), priimek varchar(20))");
```

It works good but if I close the program, start it again (with table creation lines commented out ofcourse) it says that

***java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'VODICI' does not exist.***

when I want to access table from my program. What is wrong, there is no persistence?

Comment: I know that a create table doesn't need a commit; I would still try out the behavior by having auto commit set to true.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause. Please post your comment as answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Scorpion I don't know if you saw my last comment and here is a reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the comment to a reply; please try out by setting the auto commit (on connection) to true.